# Parsing a simple string with a scala packrat parser

Tags: scala, parsing, parser-combinators

I'm trying to parse a string using scala's parser combinators like this:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
import scala.util.parsing.input.CharSequenceReader

object TestPackratParser extends RegexParsers with PackratParsers {

  lazy val program: PackratParser[Any] = "start" ~ water ~ "end" ^^ (_ => println("program"))

  lazy val water: PackratParser[Any] = (""".""".r).* ^^ (_ => println("water"))

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    parseAll(phrase(program), new PackratReader(new CharSequenceReader("start something here end")))
  }

}
```

I think this should be successful because a packrat parser backtracks, so "water" will eventually match "something here".

However, it seems that "water" is matching "something here end" instead. I would have thought it shouldn't do this. Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for why the packrat parser does not backtrack, please see this [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453870/scala-packratparsers-doesn-not-backtrack-as-it-should). Said that, one way to get what you want would be the following:

```
object TestPackratParser extends RegexParsers with PackratParsers {

  override val skipWhitespace = false

  lazy val ws = """\s+""".r

  lazy val program: PackratParser[Any] = "start" ~ ws ~ water ~ ws ~ "end" ^^ (_ => println("program"))

  lazy val water: PackratParser[Any] =  words ^^ (_ => println("water"))

  val words = repsep("""\w+""".r,  ws ~ not("end") ^^ { case _ => ""})

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    parseAll(phrase(program), new PackratReader(new CharSequenceReader("start something here end")))
  }
}
```

The main idea is to use `not` when specifying the separator between words. Only if it's not `end` the `words` parser succeeds. Otherwise, the `program` parser continues.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to look at applying your type of solution to the bigger problem I had. For anyone checking back on this, I also found the [GLL combinators](https://github.com/djspiewak/gll-combinators) linked to in the other SO question very useful and they were able to handle this problem too.

Comment: Your parsing code is great. Do you have any gists / github /etc so i can see some of your other work?